# What does curated gene mean?

Tags: bioinformatics, database, gene

I see in databases "curated" or "not curated" for genes. What does that mean?

Comment: https://www.google.fr/#q=curated+genes

Comment: Welcome to Biology Stack Exchange. Could you provide an example of a database where genes are classified this way?

Comment: Thanks! For instance: http://www.wormbase.org/species/c_elegans/gene/WBGene00009562#0-9g-3
I also saw some genes that mentions as "not curated"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Curated" is mostly synonymous with "manually curated", which means that these genes have been experimentally validated. Most non-curated genes are just predicted by a software.

Answer (score 0):

In Bioinformatics, the term "curated" indicates that the information has been validated either experimentally or using predictions from a software. Often the manually and experimentally curated sections are more dependable than the ones by software. When a gene is curated, it means certain desired information about the gene such as its location on the chromosome, its function, the proteins it encodes for are known.

Comment: Welcome to BiologySE... thanks for your contribution, but can you please add some links/citations that back up your claims? We always appreciate references on the site and it will increase your reputation much more than comments/answers without any citations/references.